# Toast in ExpressJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, npm, toastr

I am unable to add a toast using expressjs. I tried using the npm package "toastr" but it throws an error that $.extend is not a function, so I tried replacing it with Object.assign but even then it wouldn't work. Can somebody help me.

This is the initial error:

[image]

This one is after changing $.extend to Object.assign inside toastr.js:

[image]

```
   app.post("/edit/:userId/:quizId/:index", (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId }, (err, foundUser) => {
    if (!err) {
      foundUser.entry.splice(req.params.index, 1, req.body);
    }

      User.updateOne({ _id: req.params.userId }, { $set: foundUser }, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        toastr.success("Successfully Updated !");
        console.log("Successfully Updated !");
        res.redirect("/quiz/" + req.params.userId);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is my code snippet.

Comment: Shouldnt the toastr part go into your frontend code

Comment: Can you please show you app.js file, front-end code AND specify the npm package you are using?

Answer (score 0):

toastr should be in the front end script.

Setup the cdn call in your layout page

```
link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css')
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js')
```

Then in your  section on your view you can call it like the below:

```
toastr.success('Contact request has been submitted');
```

I normally change my url to include a param to tell my view that the function completed either true or false. Then with the view  I check the param and if true or false I will display a toastr message.

Example:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const parameters = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const value = parameters.get('requestSent');
if(value == "true"){
  toastr.success('Contact request has been submitted');
}
```